# problem with getRetweeters with Jtwitter

Tags: java, jtwitter

my piece of code is:

```
  for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){            

        listRetweeters = null;
        tweetId = list.get(i).getId();
        status = twitter.getStatus(tweetId);
        listRetweeters= twitter.getRetweeters(status);
        System.out.println("users RT: ");
        for(int j=0;j<listRetweeters.size();j++)
            System.out.println(listRetweeters.get(j).toString());
   }
```

my problem is that at try retweeters of a tweet my return this error:

Exception in thread "main" winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException$E401: Unauthorized
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you"}]}
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/111580420944044034/retweeted_by.json (anonymous)
        at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:380)
        at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.connect(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:199)
        at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.getPage(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:240)

Thanks for response and excuse me, my basic english XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client is trying to authenticate for the getRetweeters() call, and you're using an un-authenticated Twitter object -- or perhaps one with an invalid OAuth token.

Actually, it is now not necessary to authenticate for this call. If you download the latest version of [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php), it will allow this method with anonymous clients (created using the no-argument Twitter() constructor).

Alternatively, you can use an OAuthSignpostClient() with a valid access token.